# While loop not getting executed

Tags: c, struct, while-loop, boolean, scanf

When I run this program, everything is executed except for the block of while loops at the end. Any help would be greatly appreciated. the program should print invalid if the input in base salary is not an integer but the while loop is not getting executed.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

bool isInt(char *salary) {
    int i = 0;

    if (salary[0] == '-') {
        i = 1;
    }

    for (; i < strlen(salary); i++) {
        if (salary[i] < '0' || salary[i] > '9') {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

struct employee
{
    char name[100];
    char hdate[100];
    int salary;
};

int calc(int a);

void main(){

    int j,i;
    char s2[100];

    printf("enter number of employees: ");
    scanf("%d",&j);
    struct employee s[j];

    printf("\nEnter details of employees: \n\n");
    getchar();
    for (i=0;i<j;i++){

        int n=2;

        printf("Name: ");
        fgets(s[i].name,sizeof(s[i].name),stdin);
        s[i].name[strcspn(s[i].name, "\n")] = '\0';
    

        printf("Hire Date: ");
        fgets(s[i].hdate,sizeof(s[i].hdate),stdin);
        s[i].hdate[strcspn(s[i].hdate, "\n")] = '\0';

        while (n>1)
        {
            printf("Base Salary: ");
            scanf("%d",&s[i].salary);
            sprintf(s2, "%d",s[i].salary);
            if (isInt(s2)) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                printf("Invalid ,Enter a valid Input \n");
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Employee and Salary table\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Name\t\t\tHire Date\t\t\tBase Salary\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i <j; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t\t\t%s\t\t\t%d\n",s[i].name,s[i].hdate,s[i].salary);
        printf("\nCalculations: \n");
        calc(s[i].salary);
        printf("-----------------------------------------\n");
    }
}

int calc(int a){

    int hra,da,ta,gs,pf,it,ns;

    hra=(24*a)/100;
    da=(15*a)/100;ta=4000;gs=a+hra+da+ta;
    pf=(10*a)/100;it=(5*a)/100;
    ns=gs-pf-it;

    printf("\n\tBasic Salary: %d \n\tHRA: %d \n\tDA: %d \n\tTA: %d \n\tGross Salary: %d \n\tPF: %d \n\tIncome Tax: %d \n\tNet Salary: %d\n\n",a,hra,da,ta,gs,pf,it,ns);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your checking of the input salary makes no sense. You are reading it as `int` and `sprint`ing it as `int`. There is no reason in the world the check could fail (except bugs in `isInt` function...

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of `void main()` make it `int main(void)` if you want the program to be portable. `void main()` may compile in some implementations, but many will refuse it.

Comment: Code that calls both `scanf` and `fgets` never works.  Sprinkling in random calls to `getchar` rarely helps.  Either use `scanf` everywhere, or `fgets` everywhere; don't try to mix them.

Comment: I think `return;` in the `while` loop is supposed to be `break`. `return` exits the entire `main()` function, so you'll never get to the code after the loop.

Comment: Why: `scanf("%d", &s[i].salary);` `sprintf(s2, "%d", s[i].salary);` and then `if(isInt(s2))` ?!?

Comment: __struct employee s[j]__ is a C99 feature.  What compiler are you using?  Some of them allow the syntax but do not implement properly

Comment: one independent consideration, use the return value of `scanf` to determine if the user entered a valid number or not. From the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html): _On success, these functions (including `scanf`) return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned_

Comment: perhaps O/T, but that's a weird condition for your `while` loop, considering that `n` is never modified in it. If you intend that to be an infinite loop (until it `return`s or should more likely `break`), do `while(1)`, there's no need for `n` to exist. Or modify `n` in some manner in the loop if you intend to use it to exit the loop at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the following is already covered in comments.

1. The language spec specifies exactly two signatures for the `main` function:

   ```
   int main(void);
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
   ```

   There are alternative spellings for the latter, but always choose one of these two forms, at least until you're experienced enough that you no longer need advice about C basics.
2. It is possible to mix `scanf`, `getchar`, and `fgets` if you understand these functions very well.  But if you understand these functions very well then you *won't* often mix them.  Generally speaking, you should choose just one, probably `fgets()` for most real-world programs, but maybe `scanf()` for programs that don't need to be robust against unexpected or malformed input.  `getchar()` serves special purposes.

   - And when you do use `scanf()`, it is almost always buggy to fail to check its return value and act appropriately.  That will tell you how many input fields were actually read, which may be fewer than you asked for if the input is not as expected, and it will notify you if the end of the file or an I/O error is detected.
3. The call to `isInt()` makes no sense here:

   > ```
   >             scanf("%d",&s[i].salary);
   >             sprintf(s2, "%d",s[i].salary);
   >             if (isInt(s2)) {
   >                 return;
   >             }
   > ```

   The string you are testing was formatted by `sprintf()`, so if it fails to validate as an integer then you have very serious problems that `isInt()` in no way addresses.

   It might make sense if you were reading a whole line via `fgets()` to validate the line before attempting to parse out an integer, but it would actually be easier to detect invalid inputs as a side effect of parsing (with `strtol()`, for example).
4. The `while (n>1)` loop will never terminate normally because `n` starts out as 2 and does not change in the body of the loop.  If you are intentionally writing an infinite loop then make that clear by spelling it `while (1)` or `for (;;)`.  On the other hand, if you mean to limit the number of retries then

   - you need to count the retries, maybe be decrementing `n` inside the loop
   - you need to do something appropriate when the user runs out of retries.
5. The `return` in that `while` loop terminates the execution of `main()`.  Unless the user enters 1 or more for the number of employees, that `return` will interrupt the first iteration of the outer `for` loop, which is why your program never prints a salary table.  Possibly you want a `break` instead of a `return` here, but see also above.
6. As a matter of style,

   - use more meaningful variable names
   - don't be so parsimonious with the spaces
   - avoid multiple statements on the same line
   - avoid declaring multiple variables in the same declaration
   - choose ONE:

     - `main()` **first**, with preceding forward declarations of any functions it may want to call,

     OR

     - `main()` **last**, with no forward declarations needed on account of all the function definitions preceding `main()`
       Your `main()` in the middle approach is just confusing.

Comment: and always test the return value of scanf

Comment: Agreed, @pm100, and that's in there.